# getting up for an elder on a wheelchair

Tags: halacha, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

The Torah tells us to stand up for an elder (Vayikra 19:32) passing by.

What if the elder is passing by sitting in a wheelchair?

Perhaps the reason is to show respect and not be sitting while he is standing and this reason does not apply for a sitting elder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Talmud asks this question (Kiddushin 33b) and concludes that רכוב כמהלך דמי riding is like walking (in this context, at least), and so rules the Shulchan Arukh (YD 244:2). So you would have to stand up.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that to sit on a wheel chair is Rachuv?    Concerning Tefilat hadderech,  the question is addressed,  additionally the comparison to mehalech is perhaps for himself,  bot for the others

Comment: it seems in Eruvin 64b that רכוב is as mehalech or Omed because of the lack of Yshuv Hadaat. See YD 228, 4, but you are right for rachuv at least.